# PHP Calculate Number of Weeks Between Dates and Round up to Nearest Week

Tags: php, date, rounding

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the number of weeks between to dates for billing. Billing is weekly so 1+ days = a week and 8+ days = 2 weeks and so on..

So far I have my code working out the number of weeks but it doesnt seems to round up to the nearest week even if it is only a day over (This is what I need)

I hope I have explained it correctly, this is what I have so far.

```
$strtDate = '2016-03-08';
$endDate = '2016-04-07';

echo $strtDate, $endDate;

$startDateWeekCnt = round(floor( date('d',strtotime($strtDate)) / 7)) ;
$endDateWeekCnt = round(ceil( date('d',strtotime($endDate)) / 7)) ;
$datediff = strtotime(date('Y-m',strtotime($endDate))."-01") - strtotime(date('Y-m',strtotime($strtDate))."-01");
$totalnoOfWeek = round(floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) / 7) + $endDateWeekCnt - $startDateWeekCnt ;
echo $totalnoOfWeek ."\n";
```

Does anyone know how I could ammend my code to do what I need. In the code I pasted it gives 4 weeks as the answer but It should be five as it is at least 1 day more than 4 weeks.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: I echo out the two dates by the way to aid testing :) please ignore that line

Comment: Please edit your question to have a valid end date

Comment: Thanks Daniel I have now updated the typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `ceil` instead of `round`.

```
ceil(abs(strtotime("2016-05-20") - strtotime("2016-05-12")) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7);
```

Comment: This seems to be a much easier way to solve my problem and seems to work very well. Thank you so much I am currently going to do some more in-depth testing but so far so good :D - Thanks to everyone for your answers, it is extremely helpful and much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It's far easier working with DateTime objects.

Assuming that the difference is less than a year:

```
$startDate = new DateTime($strtDate);
$interval = $startDate->diff(new DateTime($endDate));

echo ceil($interval->days / 7);
```

otherwise (if more than a year)

```
$startDate = new DateTime($strtDate);
$interval = $startDate->diff(new DateTime($endDate));

echo ceil(($interval->y * 365 + $interval->days) / 7);
```

although that doesn't take leap years into account

Comment: This looks remarkably like serialized downvoting to me (with 3/4 of the answers provided downvoted like this): if an answer is wrong, then it might justify a downvote, but otherwise I really wish SO would force downvoters to explain their actions